# PHP Regex - Value of 1 or more integers

Tags: php, regex, input, validation

Hey I'm trying to perform input validation in PHP to ensure that the stock values that are typed in are at least 1 positive integer and from 0-9. Should not contain any special characters.

For example, any of the following values should be valid:

```
7
0
32
47534
```

The following SHOULD NOT be valid:

```
asdf
35/gdf
../34.

etc..
```

I'm using the following if statement to check for the positive integer value of "$original_stock".

```
if (preg_match("/^[0-9]$/", $original_stock)) 
{
    $error .="Original stock must be numerical.";
}
```

Additionally, I have a price field which should be validated as either an int or a double.

If there's an easier alternative to using regex, that's okay too!

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this regexp:

```
/^\d+$/
```

The issue with your existing regexp is that it only matches strings with exactly one digit.

As for validating an int or a double:

```
/^\d+\.?\d*$/
```

Note that that regexp requires that there be at least one digit.

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
/^[0-9]+$/
```

The `+` means "one or more". Without it, your regex will only match a single digit. Or you could use the simpler variant:

```
/^\d+$/
```

For floats, try something like:

```
/^\d+(\.\d{1,2})?/
```

This will match one or more digits, optionally followed by a `.` and one or two digits. (i.e. `.12` will not match.)

To save yourself some headaches, you can also use the [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php) and [`is_float`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-float.php) functions.

Lastly; note that your check is wrong. `preg_match` will return 0 if it fails, so you should write it as:

```
if (!preg_match("/^\+$/", $original_stock)) {
  // error
}
```

(note the `!`).

Comment: I tried the first and the second one but if the input is "30" then it causes an error either way.

Comment: what do you mean "causes an error"? note that these regex require that there is nothing else than the number - no whitespace in particular.

Comment: It does not match using the "preg_match" function and thus assigns a string to the $error variable.

The number does not have any whitespace or anything by the way. It's just 30 and was taken straight from the database.

Comment: Edited my answer. The match works, you're not testing it correctly though.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to use the

```
is_int
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't reinvent a wheel slower than an existing one, use a motorcycle: [`is_int`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php).

```
#Assuming $original_stock is a single value...
if (is_int($original_stock)) {
    #Valid, do stuff
}
else {
    #Invalid, do stuff
}

#Assuming $original_stock is an array...
$valid = true;
foreach ($original_stock as $s) {
    if (!is_int($s)) {
        $valid = false;
        break;
    }
}
if ($valid) {...}
else {...}
```

Comment: `is_int` wont do it if the input comes from a form, only `is_numeric`. Either way, you are also validating negative integers and possibly non-integers.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this exact problem and solved it this way using the regex.
I think the problem is your caret ^.

```
/^[0-9]$/
```

I moved it inside the class and got the results I needed.

```
function validate_int($subject)
{
    //Pattern is numbers
    //if it matches anything but numbers, we want a fail
    $pattern = '/[^0-9]/'; 
    $matches = preg_match($pattern, $subject);
    if($matches > 0)
      return false;
    else
      return true;
  }
```